# Custom string representation of list depending on number of items (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to print out a list differently depending on how many items it has:

For example:

- For no items i.e. `[]` should output `{}`
- For 1 item i.e. `["Cat"]` should output `{Cat}`
- For 2 items i.e. `["Cat", "Dog"]` should output `{Cat and Dog}`
- For 3 or more items i.e. `["Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Lion"]` should output `{Cat, Dog, Rabbit and Lion}`

I currently am doing something like this with a bunch of if statements:

```
def customRepresentation(arr):
  if len(arr) == 0:
    return "{}"
  elif len(arr) == 1:
    return "{" + arr[0] + "}"
  elif len(arr) == 2:
    return "{" + arr[0] + " and " + arr[0] + "}"
  else:  
    # Not sure how to deal with the case of 3 or more items
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the words will never contain commas themselves. You could instead use **[join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)** and **[replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace)** to deal with all your cases in just one line:

```
>>> def custom_representation(l):
...   return "{%s}" % " and ".join(l).replace(" and ", ", ", len(l) - 2)
... 
>>> for case in [], ["Cat"], ["Cat", "Dog"], ["Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Lion"]:
...   print(custom_representation(case))
... 
{}
{Cat}
{Cat and Dog}
{Cat, Dog, Rabbit and Lion}
```

Comment: Beware with cases where the words themselves contain commas.

Comment: Might it be more efficient to join on `, ` and replace only the final one with `and`?

Comment: The words will never contain commas themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd go about this:

```
class CustomList(list):

    def __repr__(self):

        if len(self) == 0:
            return '{}'
        elif len(self) == 1:
            return '{%s}' % self[0]
        elif len(self) == 2:
            return '{%s and %s}' % (self[0], self[1])
        else:
            return '{' + ', '.join(str(x) for x in self[:-1]) + ' and %s}' % self[-1]
```

---

```
>>> my_list = CustomList()
>>> my_list
{}
>>> my_list.append(1)
>>> print(my_list)
{1}
>>> my_list.append('spam')
>>> print(my_list)
{1 and spam}
>>> my_list.append('eggs')
>>> my_list.append('ham')
>>> print(my_list)
{1, spam, eggs and ham}
>>> my_list
{1, spam, eggs and ham}
```

This way you have a fully functional `list`, only the representation is customised.